# Should autoscaling EC2 instances share the same db user account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I plan to setup autoscaling on my api nodes, but want them to connect to the same RDS instance (with Multi AZ).

Will i notice any performance impacts if the api nodes all share the same db account?

Otherwise, what alternatives do i have that wont complicate the deployment process significantly?

Thanks

Comment: the answer is no

Comment: What are the alternatives?

Comment: the performance of your rds instance depends on many things. the number of different db user accounts does not matter though. no need to complicate your deployment here.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. Will using the same db user between autoscaled nodes impact performance or data reliability? Or has no impact other than a potential impact to security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database user account is used to control security (eg Is the user allowed to perform a command) and logging (eg Which user deleted the table?).

Having applications on multiple Amazon EC2 instances use the same database user account will not impact performance. Two requests coming from different database users will use the same amount of resource as two requests coming from the same database user.

An exception to this would be if any database configurations restrict resources by user, such as processing queues. However, this would not be a default behavior.

Comment: Thank you John, great answer. Do you have a source for the comment regarding resources? I was looking online but didnt not come across anything which clearly states this.